# title of twitter.com

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, html-parsing

```
WebClient x = new WebClient();
string source = x.DownloadString("http://www.facebook.com/");

string title = Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;

Console.WriteLine(title);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I am using above written code to print title of a website.
 this method is working fine with almost all website except twitter.
 can any body pls tell me that how i  can get correct title from twitter.com as well.

Comment: parsing html with regex?

Comment: Tyr this regex :"(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)";

Comment: @Hamish It's fun for the whole family! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should not use regex to parse (X)HTML. Use a tool that is targeted for the specific task instead, such as [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
private static string GetPageTitle(string url)
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

    var result = doc.DocumentNode
        .DescendantNodes()
        .FirstOrDefault(node =>
            string.Compare(
                node.Name,
                "title",
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);

    return result != null ? result.InnerHtml : string.Empty;
}
```